# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Categories#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I wanna use gem ancestry for parent categories, and I received this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Categories#new PG::SyntaxError:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" LINE 1: ...ECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE (id != ) ORDER BY...
```

Stroke:

```
<%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Category.where("id != #{@category.id}").order(:name), :id, :name, {include_blank: true} %>
```

I don't know what to do anymore... this is the first time I'm getting this error

Comment: Probably `@category.id` is `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

You use interpolation

```
Category.where("id != #{@category.id}").order(:name)
```

If `@category` is new record, it hasn't `id` yet. It means it is `nil` in Ruby:

```rb
@category.id
# => nil
```

When you interpolate `nil`, it casts to empty string:

```rb
nil.to_s # => ""
```

That's because you have `(id != )` in the error message

**Solution**

So it's better to use another query with [`not`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not)

```rb
Category.where.not(id: @category.id).order(:name)
```

And finally

```
<%= form.collection_select :parent_id, Category.where.not(id: @category.id).order(:name), :id, :name, {include_blank: true} %>
```